# Making attribute table field dependent?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator, attribute-table

In an attribute table I am making new fields bounded each other by the Field Calculator. Once I have written the formula for the new field in the Field Calculator, ArcGIS make the calculation for the all field. If, in the field calculator I say that Field B = Field A + 1, and I calculate Field B, then I change value to Field A, I notice that Field B does not consequently change values. I would need to type the formula for Field B again to refresh its value. How can I make field B dependent on Field A? I have also used Ilwis software and there was just a box to be checked in its Field Calculator window; is there in ArcGIS something similar?